# GeoLite2 City Database Different Result Between IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: c#, asp.net, maxmind

I am currently using the GeoLite2 City database and I am getting different results if I query the database using an IPv4 vs an IPv6. When using IPv6, I get all of the expanded information, including the state/province and postal code. Unfortunately our server only connects to clients using IPv4 (I think its a limitation of Azure, but I am not sure) and when trying to convert from IPv4 to IPv6 I get something along the lines of this: ::ffffff::100.100.100.100.100 which is definitely not right. Here is the code I use to retrieve and convert the ip:

```
      var userHostAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;

            var ip = IPAddress.Parse(userHostAddress);
            string iPv6 = ip.MapToIPv6().ToString();
```

I've also tried manually converting code, but that did not work either. Aside from converting the IP, has anyone else experienced this? Are IPv6 more accurate with GeoLite2 database?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, IPv4 1.2.3.4 is also ::FFFF:1.2.3.4 in IPv6.

It is a IPv4 reserved range for IPv6.